# General error: 1114 The table 'catalog_category_product_index_tmp' is full,

Tags: magento2

I have try to assign  products to category but get error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table 'catalog_category_product_index_tmp' is full, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index_tmp` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT 2 AS `category_id`, `cp`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, IF(ccp.product_id IS NOT NULL, ccp.position, 0) AS `position`, IF(ccp.product_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS `is_parent`, 10 AS `store_id`, IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `cp` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `cpw` ON cpw.product_id = cp.entity_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpsd` ON cpsd.entity_id = cp.entity_id AND cpsd.store_id = 0 AND cpsd.attribute_id = 97 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpss` ON cpss.entity_id = cp.entity_id AND cpss.attribute_id = cpsd.attribute_id AND cpss.store_id = 10 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvd` ON cpvd.entity_id = cp.entity_id AND cpvd.store_id = 0 AND cpvd.attribute_id = 99 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvs` ON cpvs.entity_id = cp.entity_id AND cpvs.attribute_id = cpvd.attribute_id AND cpvs.store_id = 10 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.product_id = cp.entity_id WHERE (cpw.website_id = '1') AND (IFNULL(cpss.value, cpsd.value) = 1) AND (IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) IN (2, 3, 4)) AND (cp.entity_id IN ('44357')) GROUP BY `cp`.`entity_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` = VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)
```

Anyone know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check that your sever has free space?
(you can check it executing this command `df -h` in your server terminal).

Additional information related to that error can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/730600/5786455